# Block ciphers SALT: clear text or secret?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

There are many articles and quotes on the web saying that a 'salt' must be kept secret. Even the Wikipedia entry on [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)):

> For best security, the salt value is
>   kept secret, separate from the
>   password database. This provides an
>   advantage when a database is stolen,
>   but the salt is not. To determine a
>   password from a stolen hash, an
>   attacker cannot simply try common
>   passwords (such as English language
>   words or names). Rather, they must
>   calculate the hashes of random
>   characters (at least for the portion
>   of the input they know is the salt),
>   which is much slower.

Since I happen to know for a fact that encryption Salt (or Initialization Vectors) are OK to be stored on clear text along with the encrypted text, I want to ask **why is this misconception perpetuated** ?

My opinion is that the origin of the problem is a common confusion between the encryption salt (the block cipher's **initialization vector**) and the hashing 'salt'. In storing hashed passwords is a common practice to add a nonce, or a 'salt', and is (marginally) true that this 'salt' is better kept secret. Which in turn makes it not a salt at all, but a key, similar to the much clearly named **secret** in [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). If you look at the article [Storing Passwords - done right!](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp) which is linked from the Wikipedia 'Salt' entry you'll see that is talking about this kind of 'salt', the password hash. I happen to disagree with most of these schemes because I believe that a password storage scheme should also allow for [HTTP Digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), in which case the only possible storage is the HA1 digest of the username:realm:password, see [Storing password in tables and Digest authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000281/storing-password-in-tables-and-digest-authentication).

If you have an opinion on this issue, please post here as a response.

1. Do you think that the salt for block cipher encryption should be hidden? Explain why and **how**.
2. Do you agree that the blanket statement 'salts should be hidden' originates from salted hashing and does not apply to encryption?
3. Sould we include stream ciphers in discussion (RC4)?

Comment: Salt is not really ever used in the context of symmetric ciphers (aka RC4) or even encryption for that matter. Salt doesn't really add any security to encryption functions. Further,  salts and Initial Vectors are different things. Salts are used in conjunction with hashing functions such as SHA.

Comment: "Since I happen to know for a fact that encryption Salt (or Initialization Vectors) are OK to be stored on clear text along with the encrypted text" - can you clarify how (or where) you obtained this "fact"? - The misconception (if that's what it is) is likely due to the information not being widely available and shared across the community.

Comment: @scunliffe: basically it can be reduced to "Josh Benaloh personally told me that salt/IV can be stored and transmitted in clear".

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about IV in block cipher, it definitely should be in clear. Most people make their cipher weaker by using secret IV.

IV should be random, different for each encryption. It's very difficult to manage a random IV so some people simply use a fixed IV, defeating the purpose of IV.

I used to work with a database with password encrypted using secret fixed IV. The same password is always encrypted to the same ciphertext. This is very prone to rainbow table attack.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about IV in block cipher and the dangers of reusing the same IV for repeated encryption.

Comment: Why on earth would a "secret IV" weaken a cipher in any way? The main criteria for a good IV is to never use the same one. A secret cipher that changes is just as good as a public one that changes...

Comment: How are you going to keep track of the changing IV if it's secret? You need both the key and IV to decrypt so IV can't be encrypted. The only practical way to keep it secret is to use a fixed value, almost like an extension to the key.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you think that the salt for block
>   cipher encryption should be hidden?
>   Explain why and how

No it shouldn't. The strength of a block cipher relies on the key. IMO you should not increase the strength of your encryption by adding extra secrets. If the cipher and key are not strong enough then you need to change the cipher or key length, not start keeping other bits of data secret. Security is hard enough so keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Like LFSR Consulting says:

> There are people that are much smarter
>   than you and I that have spent more
>   time thinking about this topic than
>   you or I ever will.

Which is a loaded answer to say the least. There are folks who, marginally in the honest category, will overlook some restraints when money is available. There are a plethora of people who have no skin at the fire and will lower the boundaries for that type,....

then, not too far away, there is a type of risk that comes from social factors - which is almost impossible to program away. For that person, setting up a device solely to "break the locks" can be an exercise of pure pleasure for no gain or measurable reason. That said, you asked that those who have an opinion please respond so here goes:

1. Do you think that the salt for block
   cipher encryption should be hidden?
   Explain why and how.

Think of it this way, it adds to the computational strength needed. It's just one more thing to hide if it has to be hidden. By and of it's self, being forced to hide ( salt, iv, or anything ) places the entity doing the security in the position of being forced to do something. Anytime the opposition can tell you what to do, they can manipulate you. If it leaks, that should have been caught by cross-controls that would have detected the leak and replacement salts available. There is no perfect cipher, save otp, and even that can be compromised somehow as greatest risk comes from within.

In my opinion, the only solution is to be selective about whom you do *any* security for - the issue of protecting salts leads to issues that are relevant to the threat model. Obviously, keys have to be protected. If you have to protect the salt, you probably need to review your burger flippin resume and question the overall security approach of those for whom you are working.

There is no answer, actually.

2. Do you agree that the blanket statement 'salts should be hidden' originates from salted hashing and does not apply to encryption?

Who said this, where, and what basis was given.

3. Should we include stream ciphers in discussion (RC4)?

A cipher is a cipher - what difference would it make?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a per record salt is to make the task of reversing the hashes much harder. So if a password database is exposed the effort required to break the passwords is increased. So assuming that the attacker knows exactly how you perform the hash, rather than constructing a single rainbow table for the entire database they need to do this for every entry in the database.

The per record salt is usually some combination of fields in the record that vary greatly between records. Transaction time, Account Number, transaction Number are all good examples of fields that can be used in a per record salt. A record salt should come from other fields in the record. So yes it is not secret, but you should avoid publicising the method of calculation.

There is a separate issue with a database wide salt. This is a sort of key, and protects against the attacker using existing rainbow tables to crack the passwords. The database wide salt should be stored separately so that if the database is compromised then it is unlikely that the attacker will get this value as well.

A database wide salt should be treated as though it was a key and access to the salt value should be moderately protected. One way of doing this is to split the salt into components that are managed in different domains. One component in the code, one in a configuration file, one in the database. Only the running code should be able to read all of these and combine them together using a bit wide XOR.

The last area is where many fail. There must be a way to change these salt values and or algorithm. If a security incident occurs we may want to be able to change the salt values easily. The database should have a salt version field and the code will use the version to identify which salts to use and in what combination. The encryption or hash creation always uses the latest salt algorithm, but the decode verify function always uses the algorithm specified in the record. This way a low priority thread can read through the database decrypting and re-encrypting the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Each encrypted block is the next block IV. So by definition, the IV cannot be secret. Each block is an IV.

The first block is not very different. An attacker who knows the length of the plain text could have a hint that the first block is the IV.

- BLOCK1 could be IV or Encrypted with well known IV
- BLOCK2 is encrypted with BLOCK#1 as an IV
- ...
- BLOCK N is encrypted with BLOCK#N-1 as an IV

Still, whenever possible, I generate a random (non-null) IV and give it to each party out-of-band. But the security gain is probably not that important.