# Where do I salt and hash my Passwords? At the client or at the host?

Tags: security

I think it would be smarter to salt and hash passwords directly on the client's machine. The reason is, that I actually never want to get the password of the user. It is a string that should be secret to him, not to both of us. Now someone argued, that you want to keep the salt a secret, so you can not send it in clear text over the channel. [Apparently, that is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552554/salting-hashs-why-is-the-salt-treated-by-literature-as-beeing-known-to-eve). So now I don't see any reason, why I shouldn't just request a hash from the client side. What do you think?

*edit* to discuss the issue of sending a clients password to the host is actually not directly the issue. The issue for the client is to send the password out of his computer at all. An optimistic client may assume that his computer is save territory. But everything going out of that cable (or antenna) is Eve's territory. You can never be **too** paranoid in a security scenario. So again: The password should **never** leave the clients computer!

Comment: @tjm, even if you receive the hashed (and maybe also salted) version of the password, it should *still* be sent over an encrypted connection to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: @Mike, of course yes. It should *always* be sent over an encrypted connection. Thank-you for clarifying. I'll delete my previous comment to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Mike: encrypting it does not, in itself, prevent a replay attack. In a typical case you send the hashed, encrypted passphrase only once, when establishing the account. That means even if somebody attempts to replay it, that just creates another account with the same password, or the attempt is denied because they're trying to create an account that already exists.

Comment: You are likely to find that if the password never leaves the client's computer, the server never lets the client connect - there is no reason for the server to trust the client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sending *either* the passphrase or its hash lets an attacker record the hash and use it in a replay attack.

You generally want to use a challenge/response protocol, which means you send out a random number. The client encrypts (or does a keyed hash on) that random number using the hash of their passphrase as the key, and sends back the result. You do the same, and see of the two match.

This lets you verify matching keys without every sending the key itself across the insecure channel.

As for how you get the data initially to be able to do that comparison, yes, you usually want the client to hash the passphrase, then encrypt it with the server's public key, and send the result of that encryption.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: like asket @Jonathan Leffler: isn't called 'nonce' what you have described as 'salt'?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: That is the first time someone convinces me the need of both parties for securing who they are talking to can be achieved without exchanging core secrets. I assume, that includes that you should also sent the salt to the client, because it must be applied before he starts the hashing. How do you do that? Is plain text for that enough?

Comment: @Overbose: I don't think I described *anything* as salt, but yes, a nonce is another word for the challenge (but nonce is a more general term -- a nonce can also be used as an IV or an encryption key, for example).

Comment: @erikb: yes -- a salt is normally expected to be public knowledge in any case; it doesn't need to be kept secret to do its job.

Comment: @@Jerry Coffin: no you don't :) sorry. But you described a challenge-response mechanism. I wrote in a comment to Jonathan Leffler  what I was used to call salt. That I thought a bit different from challenge-response's nonce.

Comment: @Overbose: yes -- your description there matches how I normally use "salt", and I believe that's fairly standard (e.g., matches use in *Applied Cryptography* and *Handbook of Applied Cryptography*).

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with that is that the salted, hashed password then travels over the network, and if anyone intercepts it, they can use it.

What might work is if the server sends the salt to be used to the client, and the client then sends back the salted, hashed password using the server-created salt.  The attacker might be able to capture the reply, but it won't help since the server's salt will be different each time, so the response from the client will be different each time.  However, that requires the server to know the password so that it can rehash it with the salt, defeating one of your goals.

Fundamentally, the server has to end up knowing something to ensure that the client isn't spoofing it; and the classic way to do that is to have the server store the salted, hashed password and the client sends the password to the server, which validates what the client sends by salting and hashing the sent password and comparing the result with what it has stored.  This avoids the server keeping the password in clear text, but does mean that the password travels over the wire.  Make sure that the password is encrypted before being sent, therefore.

Comment: Leffler: isn't called 'nonce' what you have described as 'salt'? Mine is not an objection, just a question. I thought that the salt was something different.

Comment: @0verbose: yes, another name for what I called 'salt' in the 'server-sends-challenge' variant is 'nonce'.  It is basically the same as a 'salt'.  Either way, the client has to use a value sent by the server to hash the password, and the server has to know the password so it can repeat the hash and check that it gets the correct value from the client.

Comment: Leffler @Jerry Coffin : ok . good to know . I thought that the salt was a different think. Like in unix password files, where it is concatenated to the password to prevent different users with the same passphrase to generate the same hashed password. And also increasing the key space, and the computational time to eventually break the pass.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: No. The server doesn't need the password. The server needs the salted hash. He just needs to make sure he get's the real salted hash in the first place. Then he has something to compare later hashes against. If he really would need the password for anything, he actually would need to store it in plain text or at least encrypted in a decryptable way.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, hashing is meant to obfuscate actual passwords and doesn't protect against replay attacks. You need a secure sockets layer for ensuring the channel is protected.

What hashing is good for is to protect against information leaks. For instance, say someone got hold of your users table and now they have a great deal of accounts. Since people reuse passwords, the accounts can be used to attack other sites. Hashing makes it difficult to reverse the hash into a password.

You want to hash a password at the client side only if you are going to store that password locally, such as a mobile device. Generally, you want to do the hashing at the server level.

Comment: You think, that you as the software engineer are the clients friend. But that is not the case. To him you are just another guy that might use his secrets against him. In the least he can't trust you to really do your job concerning security well enough, as companies like Sony have proven.

Comment: How does a locally stored hashed password get used?  You can't invert that hashing.

Comment: You'd use locally stored hashes as cache to validate if connectivity drops in mobile apps. This way you have someway of allowing one to use the app offline, while still giving a modicum of protection.