# Secure client / server authentication protocol

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

I'm working on a client / server application. I have connected the two sides via NIO and their connection is secured by SSL. Now I want the server to authenticate the login credentials the user has entered on client side. Unfortunately there is an abundance of contradictory information out there.

This thread [Is it ok to send plain-text password over HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/is-it-ok-to-send-plain-text-password-over-https) states that

> It is standard practice to send "plaintext" passwords over HTTPS.

which makes me think it should be fine in my case too.

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553363/where-do-i-salt-and-hash-my-passwords-at-the-client-or-at-the-host) say

> You generally want to use a challenge/response protocol

I want the application to be as safe as it can be. The connection is already protected by TLS 1.2 and SSL but from what I understand this does not make man-in-the-middle attacks impossible which makes me want to implement challenge–response authentication. But this collides with a different server-side security measure I had planned: [salting](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

This is what I would imagine a protocol that incorporate challenge-response and salting would have to be:

- client sends username
- server responds with random challenge and user's salt
- client hashes password and salt, then hashes it again with the challenge and sends the combined hash to server
- server retrieves the correct password hash from a database, hashes it using the challenge and checks the result against the hash the client sent

I have two problems with this protocol.

1. It sends clients a user's salt before the password has been verified. I know the salt is not secret but it still feels wrong.
2. Someone could hack a client and exploiting this protocol would enable them to check if users exist and get any user's salt.

**EDIT:**

Problem 2. can be solved by having the server respond with a random salt in case the user does not exist as Patrick Mevzek pointed out in the comments. That way even a hacked client would not know whether the username or password was wrong.

Comment: HTTPS does make MITM attacks impossible.

Comment: @user207421 only if client thoroughly validate the server certificate, which is not always the case. And if the client does not manage its trust store itself, some may manage to get a certificate from another CA and hence impersonate, based on what the client is really checking.

Comment: So what would you do? Just send the password in plaintext?

Comment: As for 2) : the server reply should not be different between "user does not exist" and "password mismatch". If that is guaranteed, then an attacker will never be able to check if users exist (until it also find the relevant password). Which means the server should be doing step 2 even if username does not exist (using a random salt there as it does not matter anymore)

Comment: HTTPS contains server hostname verification. That's why I wrote HTTPS instead of TLS.

Comment: When you log in through any HTTPS website, you send your login information in clear but inside the TLS encrypted stream. The server gets the password in clear. This is not contradictory to salting, which is a technique used to store the hashed (in fact key derived, see PBKDF2/argon/bcrypt/scrypt) password on server side.

Comment: @user20742 "HTTPS contains server hostname verification." And? Names can be spoofed, either at the DNS (except if you use DNSSEC) or BGP level. And with DV certificates, if that traffic is diverted anyone could get a certificate for such a name, hence HTTPS itself is not enough. Otherwise people would not have invented key pinning or TLSA records.

Comment: Please do not say "The connection is already protected by TLS and SSL". This makes no sense. TLS was invented 20 years ago, and is the successor of SSL, which does not exist anymore today due to security reason. The lowest version to run nowadays is really TLS 1.2, and 1.3 exists now and should be the default. "The connection is already protected by TLS" is far enough!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks, your solution to problem 2. is perfect. I will edit the question and add your idea. With that change would you consider the protocol secure?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Sorry, I meant TLS 1.2 (and I'm switching to 1.3).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek And every online banking application I have ever used relies on it.

Comment: "With that change would you consider the protocol secure?" I still do not understand what you have against plain text password inside HTTPS. This is what everyone does. Otherwise look at SRP, but then you will find https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/why-is-srp-not-widely-used with details on why basically you see it almost nowhere. Plaintext inside HTTPS is fine, if you do instead your own protocol over TLS you can then do some challenge-response or SRP etc... Depends if you control both sides or not.

Comment: (Remembering that even if password is plain text inside TLS it has not - and should not in fact - to be stored as plaintext on the server, to be verified)